# jQuery to load 10 items at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I need to display 10 `Song` objects at a time with a load more button at bottom that loads 10 more results. This keeps on happening until no more results are available and the load more button is not displayed at that time.

This is what i've come up with

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#song_list div:lt(10)').show();
    //var items =  ?
    //var shown =  ?
    $('#loadMore').click(function () {
        shown = $('#song_list div:visible').size()+10;
        if(shown<items) {$('#song_list div:lt('+shown+')').show();}
        else {$('#myList li:lt('+items+')').show();
          $('#loadMore').hide();
          }
    });
});
```

How can I get the values of number of items and number of items shown?

This is the code to display the song list

```
<div id='song_list'>
    {% for song in dj_song_list %}
    <div>
        <p class="song"><h3>#{{ forloop.counter}} {{ song.name }}</h3></p>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
<button id='loadMore'>Load more</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close the paragraph...`"</p>"`

```
<div id='song_list'>
    {% for song in dj_song_list %}
    <div>
        <p class="song"><h3>#{{ forloop.counter}} {{ song.name }]</h3></p>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
<button id='loadMore'>Load more</button>
```

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/gebm4/2/

```
var max_items_page = 2;

$('#song_list div:lt('+max_items_page+')').show();
var shown = null;
var items = $("#song_list").find('div').length;

$('#loadMore').on('click',function(e){
    shown = $('#song_list div:visible').length+max_items_page;
    if(shown<items) {
        $('#song_list div:lt('+shown+')').show();
    }else {
        $('#myList li:lt('+items+')').show();
        $('#loadMore').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the question. That was just a typing mistake.

Comment: The closing p tag is not required in this case since there is no more content after it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p

Comment: the size method was deprecated in 1.8, fyi

Comment: That's true, thanks @KevinB. replaced with length **(The .size() method is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. Use the .length property instead.)**;

Comment: It throws an exception
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'

Comment: I was using an older version. Using 1.7 removes those exceptions, but the code still doesn't seem to be working on my website. It displays all the results. I can't seem to figure out why.

Comment: #song_list > div {display:none;}

Comment: I didn't understand this code. Could you elaborate a bit on what it does? Using this causes no results to displayed and displays only the Load more button.

Comment: @EduardoStuart But using `#song_list div {display:none;}` in my code causes no result to be displayed.

Comment: are you sure your javascript is being executed? put a alert or a console.log...to check this. The css code hide everything...but, the js show's the first 10 results (**$('#song_list div:lt('+max_items_page+')').show();**)

Comment: The jquery file being linked had a spelling mistake in the file name. My bad. It's working now. Thanks a lot for bearing with me and helping out.